How to make Star Schema having 2 Fact Tables?

I have an assignment which I cannot understand due to several reasons:
-Assignment itself says we have 2 fact tables
-At the same time it is needed to create Star Schema
I have no idea how I can make a Star Schema out of basically Snowflake schema. I tried to merge 2 fact tables on CompanyName..
Maybe I misinterpreted an assignment?
Please help to find my mistake.
**Assignment:
**
Input data description.
There are 3 excel files in Data folder:

“SpendCategories.xlsx” contains dimensions of 2-level spend categorization.  “Spend Categories” sheet defines parent level. “Spend Subcategories” sheet defines the lowest level of granularity and has a reference to parent category identifier.

“CompanySpends.xlsx” contains fact data about companies’ spending transactions over time.    “Spend Transactions” sheet defines the actual spends. “Company Budgets” sheet shows the defined company spend budgets (broken down by quarters).

“CompanyIncomes.xlsx” contains fact data about companies’ incoming transactions (paid by the customers they work with)  “Income Transactions” sheet defines the actual incoming transactions. Has a reference to customer. “Customers” sheet defines customers dimension and additionally includes the customer’s Country & City. Country & City values have been exported from a third-party system and not yet preprocessed for analytics purposes (it will be needed for page 4 which is optional)



Load data from excel files. It is necessary to clean the garbage in some tables (for example, empty lines in spend transactions). Clean the data not in Excel, but in the Power BI transformations (Power Query). 

Build Power BI data model with all necessary relations. Use Star Schema
I tried to merge 2 fact tables (Spend Transactions and Income Transactions on CompanyName)..

Hi - why do you think a star schema can’t have multiple fact tables? The term “star schema” is just a loose generic description of a data model made up of fact and dimension tables. Also, “snowflake” tends to mean where dimensions are joined to other dimensions and not to facts - so the number of facts you have doesn’t make your schema a snowflake (or not)

I don't really see the need to combine the two fact tables into one, but if you want to do that you would append, not merge. The Income and Spend fact tables don't have a relationship, so you cannot merge these tables.
If you append them, your resulting table would have all the common columns (Budget relationship), plus some columns that only appear in the Income table (customer relationship) and some columns that only appear in the Spend table (Spend categories).
You might also want to introduce a new column that clearly identifies each entry as either Spend or Income before you append the two tables.
You could merge the Categories and the Sub-Categories table into one wider dimension table, so you don't have a cascading relationship. That would be the more poignant difference between the current schema and a star schema.

If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.
